# Prefix CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css

How can I prefix all CSS selectors easily?

In my CSS file  I have lot of classes but I don't want those styles applied to the whole HTML but a specific div.

For Example,

```
//In css file
.myClass{
//Some Styling
}

//In HTML

<div class=myClass></div>
<div id="styleOnlyInsideMe">
<div class=myClass></div>
</div>
```

If I could prefix my selector with id

```
#styleOnlyInsideMe .myClass{
    //Some Styling
    }
```

The `myClass` style will be only applied to div inside #styleOnlyInsideMe.
Is there an alternate way to achieve this? I want this because, I want to avoid the conflict when I insert the boot-strap css into my page.

**What if I write code to replace all text between '}' and '{' , and replace the word in between by prefixing the new id?**

Comment: I feel a find & replace coming on? find: `.myClass` replace: `#styleOnlyInsideMe .myClass` should do it :-) - most text editors will do this for you

Comment: I did not understand if the `id` is a problem of you are just looking for other solutions to solve the problem

Comment: @DannyHearnah But .myClass is just an example. I want to rename the whole css file. it may contain other selectors with different names. Sometimes id selectors, class selectors tag selectors etc

Comment: use SASS or LESS to easily add the prefix to all classes at once.

Comment: @SubinJacob check out my answer below.. this should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a text editor that will support regex find & replace you could do something like this:

I'm using notepad++

Prefix all `classes`
Find: `(\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\s*\{)`
Replace: `#yourID \1`

Prefix all `IDs` Find: `(\#-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\s*\{)`
Replace: `#yourID \1`

before:

```
.p_container {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}

.step {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

after:

```
#yourID .p_container {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}

#yourID .step {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

**Edit**

The closest I could get to automated is the following situation:

Run

Find: `((\.-?)(.*?)(?=\,))` Replace `#yourID \1` - find comma seperated classes

Find: `((\#-?)(.*?)(?=\,))` Replace `#yourID \1` - find comma seperated id's

Find: `((\.-?)(.*?)(?=\{))` Replace `#yourID \1` - find classes

Find: `((\#-?)(.*?)(?=\{))` Replace `#yourID \1` - find divs

Find `(\n[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-])(.*?)(?=\{)` Replace `#yourID \1` - find element selectors

I wonder if anyone can work out a better way of doing this.. the element selector i found difficult, so probably can be improved!

Find `#yourID #yourID` Replace `#yourID` - replace possible duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can use scss to auto prefix your classes.

create a file **mystyle.scss**

```
#styleOnlyInsideMe {
    /*Your entire css*/
    .myClass {
      /*your styles*/
    }
}
```

then in your command-prompt/terminal run

```
node-sass mystyle.scss mystyle.css
```

This way all your css will be prefixed with `#styleOnlyInsideMe`

You can learn about node-sass here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: thanks for your answer; saved me a lot of pain; not sure why it's not the accepted answer.